# Shuttle driver for service customers at a privately owned franchised car dealership in Illinois

Tags: employer-relations

I work in a privately owned car Dealership in Illinois. I drive a shuttle van for them. There are two of us who work the day shift. Something that might be relevant, the other employee rents an apartment from our direct supervisor and her mother works here in a management position as well. She has called in over five times in the last month, and her reason was, for each time, I’m dead serious here, that her puppy was sick.

A petty instance of her personality: we have company provided cell phones that we must leave at work. I came to work one day and see only a broken charger in the cupboard. The one I use was not broken when I returned it the day before. When I asked her about it, she openly admitted to breaking it and having the unbroken one, but refused to give me the unbroken one. "I don't want that one, I use my phone more than you", she says (true, for personal calls that we are not supposed to be using them for). That's just her personality. Today prompted me to come here seeking advice. She left less than two hours into our shift. She says to me, "I don't feel like being here, I'm going home". And she just left. Without asking a supervisor if she could and only telling me she was. I have been to my supervisor about all the situations, including today, to my supervisor's supervisor, and our HR supervisor. Nothing is being done. The added stress and expectations on me to fill her shoes is now unbearable. I'm not in a financial position where I can just up and quit. It took me awhile to land this job.

Consider that I've already spoken to management, what other options do I have to reduce the added stress for me besides quitting?

Update: Thank you very much to those who gave their time and assistance. I feared there wasn't really much I could do except either "deal" with it and/or look for another job in the meantime. I would love to not focus on her, if only the added work load didn't fall on me. Being the only shuttle driver here when she literally doesn't feel like coming in, I can't just say to customers, "I'm sorry, but I'm the only one here so I can only take you, you and you back to work while your vehicle is being serviced". I know when reading posts we think in logical terms, we are shown for entertainment TV shows/movies that have people who act mostly logically (a person is drowning and a passerby will try to help on TV/in movies), but in real life, things do not always go logically, I would say almost rarely in fact. In real life people don't want to get involved, don't want people to dislike them, don't want possible confrontations, don't want to "deal" with it, so burying heads and hoping the situation will handle itself is very common. So please believe me when I say nothing is being done. There are other issues with her that affect other employees that have been mentioned to supervisors, such as she doesn't shower and frequently has a very unpleasant odor; she openly admits she doesn't like to shower. Only last week however, she was given a raise. PS It is not the raise per se, I've been here much longer and still make more, only that she got one considering...

Comment: I am sorry to hear this @RhondaT . However "can the company keep allowing her this" is something that only your company HR or manager can answer, we can't know for sure. Could you please edit your question and rephrase it so it is actually something we can answer and help you with?

Answer (score 3):

> My question is, can the company keep allowing her to get away with this, and is there any other option for me besides quitting?

Yes. The company *can* let her do whatever she wants. I'd suspect that there are at least a few of the people in upper management that don't appreciate her behavior, but it's also not your place to police her behavior.

You have lots of options. You can continue to focus on her behavior and be miserable or you can focus on you and your behavior, it's really your choice. Keep in mind that when you say "Nothing's being done." what you're really saying is that you aren't privvy to what's being done. No supervisor or manager is going to tell you what they're doing to address another employee's poor behavior.

You can choose to look for another job while working as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are certain legal limitations on behaviors that a company can deem tolerable--harassment, abuse, dishonest accounting, etc.  Unfortunately, it doesn't sound like your co-worker's behavior meets that criteria.  If you've spoken to HR and management and they're really not doing anything to address the situation (I doubt that's actually the case), chance are you're out of luck.  Start looking for a new job in your spare time.  In the mean time, don't do anything outside of your official job duties.  If you're scheduled to work only certain hours, don't feel that you have to go overboard making up for your colleague's shortcomings.  Don't feel like you have to carry the weight of the entire company on your shoulders.